# The ring of all subrings of a ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Given a ring $A$ with identity we can define a ring of all its subrings, with addition and multiplication defined by $S+R=\left<\{s+r: s\in S, r\in R\}\right>$ and $SR=\left<\{sr:s\in S, r\in R\}\right>$ In this way the multiplication and addition behave very badly.

So is there another nice way to keep the addition information from the original ring $A$ but also giving nice properties for addition of subrings?(The most important one is the additive inverse).

As practice let’s say we have defined a nice structure for it, say $K$ is the ring of all its subrings with all suitable operations. Now let’s view integral closure as a “homomorphism” from $K$ to itself. A subring is integrally closed if it maps to itself and a $A$ is integral over a subring $R$ if it maps to $A$(if $A$ by any chance is the addition identity after a suitable definition for addition we can describe the set of all subrings which $A$ is integral over them as the kernel of the integral closure homomorphism.)

Add: As Alex pointed out, the multiplication identity can be canonically given by the image of the homomorphism $h: \mathbb{Z}\to A$ defined in the obvious way.

Comment: If $A = \Bbb{Z}$, then $\{0, 1\}$ is not a subring.

Comment: Please do not delete your previous comment. There is still a problem: you say that $A$ is a ring with identity. So what is the *trivial subring*? Furthermore, is $A$ commutative?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I re-edit the question. $A$ is not necessarily commutative. There’s nothing as the “trivial subring” in a ring. My apologies.

Comment: The subsets $S+R$ and $SR$ you define above are not generally subrings. Did you want $S+R$ to be the smallest subring of $A$ containing all such sums, and likewise with $SR$? J.-E. Pin points out a problem with your previous definition of the "trivial subring". Perhaps you can fix it by taking the ''trivial'' subring to be the image $T$ of the unique ring morphism $\mathbb{Z} \to A$; it seems to me that this $T$ has the property that $TS = ST = S$ for any subring $S$ of $A$.

Comment: There might be a lot of problems in my question since I only intuitively guess some properties to hold but it turns out they don’t. So I am looking for a better operation fot the properties to hold. I will edit my question again to make informations in my question precise.

Comment: I think the most sensible version of your question is to study the *semiring of ideals of a ring*.